# Работа с FragmentPageAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, fragmentpageradapter

Нужна помощь. Ломаю голову какой день. Помогите, пожалуйста!) Имеется Drawwer Layout c NavigationView. Суть приложения, что при нажатии на меню в контейнере появляется фрагменте с TabLayout (2 вкладки). Структура вкладок TabLayout одинаковы, меняются только данные, подгружаемые из интернета. При первом нажатии на меню все работает, но если нажать на другой пункт меню,то информация во вкладках TabLayout не меняется, то есть остается информация от первого нажатия (ЖЦ фрагментов вкладок вызывается не полностью, останавливается на OnResume), а во ViewPager не вызывается методы getItem, getPageTitle, getCount и тд.

Класс TestFragment, который запускается по нажатию на пункт из NavifatiinDrawer

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "TestFrag";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test,container,false);


    Bundle bundle = getArguments();


    String url_team = bundle.getString("DIVISION");//ссылка на список команд
    String url_table = bundle.getString("TABLE");//ссылка на турнирную таблицу



    ViewPager viewPager1 = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerTest);
    setupViewPager(viewPager1, bundle);

    TabLayout tabLayout1 = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutTest);
    tabLayout1.setupWithViewPager(viewPager1);

    return view;
}

private  void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, Bundle bundle){
    TabsFragmentAdapter adapter = new TabsFragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    Class fragmentClass1,fragmentClass2;
    fragmentClass1 = FirstFragment.class;
    fragmentClass2 = SecondFragment.class;
    Fragment fragment1 = null, fragment2 = null;
    try {
        fragment1 = (Fragment) fragmentClass1.newInstance();
        fragment1.setArguments(bundle);
        fragment2 = (Fragment) fragmentClass2.newInstance();
        fragment2.setArguments(bundle);
    } catch (java.lang.InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    adapter.addFragment(fragment1);
    adapter.addFragment(fragment2);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Класс TabsFragmentAdapter осуществляет работу с складками

```
public class TabsFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

private static final String TAG = "TabFr" ;
private String[] tabs;


private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();


public TabsFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);



    tabs = new String[]{
            "Таблица",
            "Команды",
    };

}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabs[position];
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabs.length;
}


public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
}
```

Что самое интересное ЖЦ фрагмента касса TestFragment осуществляется полностью. Читал что что нужно в адаптер передавать не getFragmentManager, а getChildFragmentManader, но результат не поменялся. Помоги, пожалуйста!!